# Dropwizard: Need to shutdown the dropwizard application gracefully gracefully

Tags: java, dropwizard

When I send a stop signal(either with `kill -SIGINT <pid>` or `System.exit(0)` or `environment.getApplicationContext().getServer().stop()`) to the application, it waits for the **shutdownGracePeriod** (by default 30 sec or whatever I configure in .yml file) and also it does not accept new request. **However**, my requirement is to make the server wait for the ongoing request to complete before stopping. The ongoing request may take 30 sec or 30 minutes, it is unknown. Can somebody suggest me the way to achieve this?

Note: I've referred to the below links but could not achieve.

- [How to shutdown dropwizard application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812816/how-to-shutdown-dropwizard-application)
- [shutdownGracePeriod](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/7eea09b60bacb8b3503cdddfb44df00d410058ad/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/server/AbstractServerFactory.java#L160-L167)

Answer (score 0):

We've used in-app healthcheck combined with some external load balancer service and prestop scripts. A healthcheck is turned off by the prestop script, then healthcheck says it is unhealthy so no new requests are sent by the load balancer (but existing ones are processed), only after draining period a stop signal is sent to the application.

Even this though has a specified time limit. I don't know how you would monitor requests that last an unknown amount of time.